# How to add cookies to Undertow's ClientRequest?

Tags: java, undertow

```
final ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest();
request.setMethod(new HttpString(requestMethod));
                    request.getRequestHeaders().put(Headers.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked");
connection.sendRequest(request, new ClientCallback<ClientExchange>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(ClientExchange clientExchange){}
    @Override
    public void failed(IOException e){}
}
```

I am following the example for the Undertow Client API. How do I add cookies to the request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cookies are stored in the request headers. Therefore you can do that:

```
final ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest();
request.setMethod(new HttpString(requestMethod));
request.getRequestHeaders().put(Headers.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked");
request.getRequestHeaders().put(Headers.COOKIE, "name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3");

connection.sendRequest(request, new ClientCallback<ClientExchange>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(ClientExchange clientExchange){}
    @Override
    public void failed(IOException e){}
}
```